# Jenkins and Maven : how to package some files in my JAR and unpack them before running a test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, jenkins, testng

Using Jenkins to run my test suite.  As part of the setup for an integration test, I need to copy a bunch of files into a given folder.  I'd like to include these files in src/test/resources, and then somehow unpack them and copy them onto the folder before running the test.  What's the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

**Edited to add :**

Basically, I'm testing a method that needs to read some files from a folder on our hadoop cluster.  On my Jenkins box, I have a single-node hadoop "cluster" running in pseudo-distributed mode.  Thus, I need to copy those files onto the cluster before running the test.  So I need to :

A) Somehow get the files onto the Jenkins box (I was thinking it would be easiest to package them in the JAR) and

B) Copy those files onto the hadoop "cluster".

Comment: You want to unpack some of the files or all of the files?

Comment: I dont understand why you want to unpack and secondly why those files can't be part of actual code in test resources?

Comment: Sorry, I left out some details for the sake of brevity.  Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is to set the option in jenkins job so that your workspace is not cleaned up on every run. This will esure that folder structure is intact before you start the build.

Use the plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep
You can add a step before you start the build copying and unpacking [basically it will provide you unix shell to execute any commands, so its you can do anything like ftp,rsync, unjar here].

But i am not sure how will you direct your test case to use these new files, but then i have never worked on hadoop so can't comment on that.